# Single Unit Test Takes ~40-50ms But 10 Copies Majority Takes Less Than 1ms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

[image]

Fixture

```
    public class AllFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public AllFixture()
        {
            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => { mc.AddProfile(new UserStoryProfile()); });
            var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

            List<UserStory> userStories = new()
            {
                new UserStory
                {
                    UserStoryId = 1,
                    Title = "One",
                    Content = "User story one."
                },
                new UserStory
                {
                    UserStoryId = 2,
                    Title = "Two",
                    Content = "User story two."
                }
            };

            Repository = new Mock<IUserStoryRepository>();
            Repository.Setup(x => x.GetUserStories()).Returns(userStories);
            Controller = new UserStoriesController(Repository.Object, mapper);
        }

        public Mock<IUserStoryRepository> Repository { get; set; }
        public UserStoriesController Controller { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    };
```

Test

```
    [Collection("Controller Collection")]
    public class ControllerTestSuite
    {
        private readonly AllFixture _allFixture;

        public ControllerTestSuite(AllFixture allFixture)
        {
            this._allFixture = allFixture;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Controller_GetUserStories_Returns_Ok1()
        {


            // Arrange
            //IUserStoryRepository rpo = _allFixture.Repository.Object;
            UserStoriesController ctr = _allFixture.Controller;

            // Act
            IActionResult result = ctr.GetUserStories();
            var items = result as OkObjectResult;

            var i = items.Value as List<UserStory>;

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.NotNull(items);
            
        }
```

Tests 1 through 10 as shown in the screenshot are all *identical* code.  The number at the end of each test name is just to prevent test name clash errors; there is no distinction in code between each test.

Why then, if I run *one* test by itself do I see a duration of ~40-50ms but if I copy/paste 10 of these and run all 10 at once do I see majority durations of less than 1ms?

In many runs of all 10 tests there is *always* one test that takes ~40-50ms to run, and this skews the overall run time of these tests.

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise (Live Unit Testing disabled), xUnit, .NET 6 with the following CPU and Memory:

[image]

[image]

Also tests are set to run in parallel.  Can someone please explain to me what's going on to cause this?  Thanks!

[image]

Well these profiler times don't make sense to me when compared to the duration reported in Test Explorer.  The one I have highlighted for example took more than 1 millisecond but less than the 39ms and then there is the 265ms time on that same line.  All times in Test Explorer were either under 1ms or that 39ms.  How much should I rely on Test Explorer duration times?

Jason

Comment: why are you that concerned about the time? there's a lot of things going on. you should use profiling.

Comment: If I'm writing unit tests and as I've read unit tests should run in 10ms or less ideally and a unit test I just wrote takes 40-50ms then I'd be chasing my tail trying to figure out what isn't really a problem if as I did here make 10 copies and run more than once.  Didn't know I could profile unit tests so thanks for that part.  New to software development and would like to understand what's going on to cause this for overall knowledge.

Comment: there's a chance that is the clr processing your code to initialize it.